# Opposite prediction result from Logistic regression - glm()

Tags: r, logistic-regression

My predictor has 2 levels:

```
>table(predictor)

predictor
    1     2 
12115  4257
```

and my response has also 2 levels:

```
> table(response)
response
    1     0 
12115  4257
```

So, clearly, there is a perfectly linear correlation here. But when I run logistic regression and prediction afterwards, I get this:

```
logit = glm(response~predictor, data=data, family="binomial")
pred = predict(logit, newdata=data, type="response")
```

However, the prediction gives me exactly the opposite results from the actual data:

```
pred                       1     0
  2.90070146547072e-12 12115     0
  0.999999999997099        0  4257
```

Would anyone know what went wrong here? How could this be explained?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first two tables don't tell you there's a perfect correlation. `table(predictor, response)` could. What kinds of variables are predictor and response? My guess is that at least predictor is a factor because that result isn't the reverse, it's predictor coded as 0 and 1.

Comment: Show us `table(predictor, response)` like @John asked for?

Answer (score 0):

predictor is (apparently) a factor with levels 1,2. However response is a factor with levels 0,1.

Firstly, make sure predictor is actually stored as factor; not an integer.

```
predictor <- as.factor(predictor)
```

*"However, the prediction gives me exactly the opposite results from the actual data"*

What does 'the actual data' mean: the actual value of predictor {1,2}, or the actual value of response {0,1} ?

If you want to use the output vector from `predict()` to predict the original predictor variable, you can't use it raw, you need to threshold it and index into its levels vector c(1,2). Or just use an `ifelse`:

```
pred <- predict(logit, newdata=data, type="response")
threshold <- 0.5 # or whatever threshold you use
pred <- ifelse(pred>threshold, 1, 2)
```

Also, show us table(predictor, response) like @John asked for.